# Counting number of user input using getchar() gives double the expected result, why?

Tags: c, loops, getchar

In the following example, from the book "C programming", when input characters, the program count twice.

```
main(){

long nc;

nc = 0;
while (getchar() != EOF)
    ++nc;
    printf("%ld\n", nc);
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
12
```

What's wrong?

I'am using Ubuntu and the gcc compiler.

Comment: `main()` is a deprecated signature. Never use it! Use a prototype-style signature, here: `int main(void)`. Learn modern C (i.e.  C99).

Comment: Technically this program is also broken because it's missing a `return 0` at the end of `main`. Since C99 you need an explicit `int main` but the `return` is optional. :-)

Comment: The output is correct. Create a file with exactly that input and pipe it to your program. Then compare the file length and the output. You also might want to use a hex-editor on the file to see **what** is going on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's counting properly. `getchar()` is considering the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key press also, as a newline `\n`. So 6 *user* inputs and 6 newlines. Counts match.

If you don't want the newlines to be counted as *inputs*, you need to increment the counter when the `getchar()` return value is not `\n`, something like

```
while ( (c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if  ( c != '\n')  ++nc;
    }
```

will get the job done. Note, `c` should be of type `int` to be able to handle `EOF`.

That said, as per `C99` or `C11`, for a hosted environment, the signature of `main()` should at least be `int main(void)` to conform to the standard.

Comment: Thanks. I missed something in my reading or the book doesn't say nothing about this strange behavior.

Comment: @carlitos_30 The book is probably not expecting you to hit enter every other time.

Comment: It is not strange at all. It simply tells you every character entered. You'll find the same behaviour with `scanf("%c", &ch);`

Comment: Thanks again, sir.

Comment: @carlitos_30 You're welcome. You can also [consider accepting any one of the answers that helped you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/244062).